# `psych::alpha`- explained the calculation details

Tags: r, psych

I noticed that some people included the total score of each item when calculating the  Cronbach's alpha  of the questionnaire. I don't know the reason for this?
Original link [`psych::alpha`- detailed interpretation of the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55741723/psychalpha-detailed-interpretation-of-the-output)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fW7K.png)

I'm hoping someone can help me understand the difference and implications of doing this and not doing it. Thanks

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Although your question is about R output, this is not really a programming question. Stack Overflow has a programming focus. You may have a better response to your question at Cross Validated, since your question is more of a statistical interpretation and statistical practice question.